# Working with sparse matrices in numpy and sklearn

Tags: numpy, performance, scikit-learn, regression, sparse-matrix

I have a time series dataset geenrated from some electrophysiological data. I have a frequncy dataset and the matrix is quite sparse but huge, like it contains 0.005 s time bins for 2000+ neurons recorded over an hour so the matrix is huge. I am using this to train regressions in sklearn and I was wondering if there were ways to represent the matrix more efficiently to speed up my code? Tons of the data is taken up by 0 values.

Specifically I will be using these two functions on the matrix,

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_decomposition.CCA.html

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNetCV.html

Will scipy.sparse run with sklearn functions, and will it train faster using scipy.sparse or other options?
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Comment: If 95%+ of the values are `0`, then maybe. sklearn will tell you if it accepts sparse data structures. `ElasticNetCV().fit(X, y)` takes `X{array-like, sparse matrix}`, which means sparse is fine.

Comment: Specific `sklearn` classes and functions tell you whether they work with sparse matrices.  READ THE DOCS.  `sklearn` also has some utilities that improve sparse operations (such as normalization).  As a rule of thumb I say that a sparsity (or density of nonzero values) of around 5% or less is needed to take full advantage of sparse matrices.  But that's based on tasks like matrix multiplication, not whole sklearn tasks.